# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines, handler, layout-inflater

I am working on a News App with fragments.

the main error I'm getting is

**"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.diparoy.newsexplorer/com.diparoy.newsexplorer.ui.NewsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment"**

**THIS IS MY BREAKING NEWS FRAGMENT**

```
class BreakingNewsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_breaking_news) {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentBreakingNewsBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
    private lateinit var newsAdapter: NewsAdapter
    private val TAG = "BreakingNewsFragment"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentBreakingNewsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel
        setUpRecyclerView()

        viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            when (response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                        newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.message?.let { message ->
                        Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred: $message")
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    showProgressBar()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun hideProgressBar() {
        binding.paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    private fun showProgressBar() {
        binding.paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        newsAdapter = NewsAdapter()
        binding.rvBreakingNews.apply {
            adapter = newsAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        }
    }

}
```

*THERE ARE 3 FRAGMENTS NAMELY BREKING NEWS, SEARCH NEWS AND SAVED NEWS*

**THIS IS MY NEWS ACTIVITY, where all the fragments will be displayed through bottom navigation menu through the bottom navigation controller**

```
class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityNewsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityNewsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Initialize ViewModel and Repository
        val newsRepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
        val viewModelProviderFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newsRepository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProviderFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)

        // Set up bottom navigation with NavController
        val bottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNavigationView
        val newsNavHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment

        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.navController)
    }
}
```

**THIS IS ACTIVITYNEWS.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.NewsActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/newsNavHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:background="@color/tropical_indigo"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/icon_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="#2B2D32"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*And the fragment_breakingnews has a recycler view in it*

Please help me solving this error.

I tried using viewBinding(). And also implemented some dependencies in the build.gradle. But nothing helped.